# The problem of assigning values to variables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Right

```sql
select @NewValue=(  select *  from inserted for xml path(''))
```

Error

```sql
select @NewValue=select *  from inserted for xml path('')
```

SQL Server Version: 2016

Comment: I'm guessing this is just a design choice, nothing more, nothing less

Comment: Are you asking why the grammar requires to use the parentheses? Probably because, given the complexity of a general `select` statement and the fact that statements in SQL can span multiple lines and do not have to be terminated with a semicolon, the lack of parentheses would create ambiguity.

Comment: You can't have a `SELECT` in a `SELECT` like that. It would be like having `SELECT MyColumn1 = SELECT MyCol FROM dbo.MyTable, MyColum2 = SELECT OtherCol FROM dbo.MyTable;` It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You may be confused by the fact that in expressions like `1 + 2 * 3`, parentheses are optional (unless you need to override standard operator precedence).

```
SELECT @NewValue = 1 + 2 * 3

SELECT @NewValue = (1 + 2) * 3
```

But `SELECT * FROM inserted FOR XML PATH('')` is not an expression; it's a *statement*. In many formal languages, a statement does not belong inside an expression, but SQL kindly offers you the possibility to raise **parenthesized** SELECT statements as expressions.

As pointed out by others, the parentheses are a **design decision** in SQL's syntax definition. Probably a wise design decision; the beginning of a SELECT statement is always clear, but the end of the statement is typically ambiguous. Example:

```
SELECT @NewValue = 2 * SELECT Foo FROM Bar WHERE Baz = 1 + 3
```

This could be interpreted either as:

```
SELECT @NewValue = 2 * SELECT Foo FROM Bar WHERE Baz = (1 + 3)
```

or (as `*` takes precedence over `+`):

```
SELECT @NewValue = (2 * SELECT Foo FROM Bar WHERE Baz = 1) + 3
```

When writing a parser, these are loose ends you do *not* want in your language definition.